# How to get the exact status of the Twilio outbound call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I have a requirement to save the exact status of a outbound call in my repository like
1)Not connected - When phone is switched off or Busy
2)UnAnswered - Call connected, But user did not pick up the call
3)Answered - Call picked up the user.

i have written some event listeners for "Ringing" , "Accept". But Ringing is getting even though the phone is switched off.

Comment: What Twilio products are you using? Also, refer to this blog for understanding how client side Voicemail can interfere with your results - Outsmart Voice Mail with Human Detection Using Keypress Prompts - https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions. Basically, the values are provided by the underlying telephone networks response codes and a VM answering is the same as a human answering.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get the status of an outbound call from Twilio you need to set up to receive webhook callbacks with the call status.

When you make the outbound call from `<Dial>` (as you are doing in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134671/twilio-js-sdk-unable-to-get-the-status-change-of-call)) you should set the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) to a URL in your application. When the call is complete, Twilio will make a request to that URL with parameters that will include a `DialCallStatus` which could be "completed", "answered", "busy", "no-answer", "failed" or "canceled".

You should use the call Sid and this status to update your database with the final state of the call.