# Twilio out going call is getting triggered in loop

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am Calling my customer mobile phone from my Twilio client using TWI ML app. But I observed that if the customer disconnects the call it is playing busy tone from that carrier and after that Twilio is not disconnecting that call. Call Is getting initiated for the second time also. In the second call it is getting disconnected in the middle. Is this because of Timeout I set for dial attribute? I set it to 15sec

```
 var response = new VoiceResponse();
            var dial = new Dial(callerId: twilioNumber, answerOnBridge: true);
            if (phoneNumber != null)
            {
                dial.Timeout = 15;
                dial.Number(phoneNumber);
                dial.Record=RecordEnum.RecordFromAnswer;
            }
            response.Append(dial);
            return Content(response.ToString(), "application/xml");
```

Comment: Can you share your TwiML that you are using please?

Comment: @philnash I have updated my question. Can you please check

Comment: What is the code and context where you create the call? Could that be adding to this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are finding that the call is not ending or redialling the customer when you get a busy signal, that might be something you should take up with Twilio support. Unless there is further code that is getting triggered by your call. [Get in contact with them](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and share some Call Sids where that happened.