# Twilio call hold is not working as expected

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio to call my customers from my Twilio client and want to put the user on hold whenever is needed. For that i am calling RESTAPI whenever user clicks on the "Hold" Button.
But after calling the method call is getting disconnected for My Twilio client and playing Hold sound for my customer. Can you please suggest something for this. Both the below approaches are not working

```
   var response = new VoiceResponse();
        var dial = new Dial();
        dial.Conference("Customer Waiting Room", beep: Conference.BeepEnum.False);
        response.Append(dial);
        var call = Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Read(parentCallSid: callSid).ToList();
        Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Update(new Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.UpdateCallOptions(call[0].Sid) { Twiml = response.ToString() });
        return Content(response.ToString(), "application/xml");
```

Alternative:

```
 var response = new VoiceResponse();
                response.Say("You have a caller on hold.");
                var call = Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Read(parentCallSid: callSid).ToList();
                response.Enqueue("admin");
                Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Update(new Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.UpdateCallOptions(call[0].ParentCallSid) { Twiml = response.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a direct call setup between your agent and you customer. When you move your customer call away from that, then your agent call will move on to the next TwiML instruction. If there are no further TwiML instructions available for your agent, then they will get disconnected.

To overcome this, you need to consider what you want your agent to do while your customer is on hold. It might be better, for example, to have your call take place in a conference. That way, when you put your customer on hold, the agent can remain in the conference.

Otherwise, you should provide further TwiML instructions after your agent's `<Dial>` so that they continue the call after the customer leg goes away.

Comment: Hi @philnash where can I mention the TWIML for customer and Agent seperately. As soon as I put the customer on conference ,Agent is getting disconnected and vice versa .Could you please help me with any code example.

Comment: I recommend that if you want to put people on hold that you start with them in a conference. Then you can actually use the hold feature of conferences as intended. Check out this blog post for how to do that: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-conference-hold.html

Comment: Hi @philnash I will give it a try and update you. Meanwhile could you please check my new question posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379853/how-to-check-status-of-a-twilio-client-before-connecting-call