# How to check status of a Twilio client before connecting call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio client to call my customer or receive the call from customers.
I want to play a busy voice message to customer if the Twilio client is engaged and talking to any other customer. how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can’t tell the status of a Twilio Client from outside the page it is live on. Instead it is best to manage the availability of your agents via [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter). With TaskRouter incoming calls can be queued until there is an available agent to answer. Those calls can also timeout, be assigned to other queues or be redirected to leave messages as in a voicemail system.

I recommend you look into TaskRouter.